# Prove that $\operatorname{Stab}_G(y) \cong\operatorname{Stab}_G(x).$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

> Suppose that $G$ acts on a set $X$.  Let $x,y \in X$ and suppose that $y \in G\cdot x$.
>
> Prove that
> $$\operatorname{Stab}_G(y) \cong\operatorname{Stab}_G(x).$$

Can anyone help me with this proof?

Comment: You should know by now that asking questions without context is generally frowned upon. Please [edit] the question to include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: What do you denote $={\sim}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $G$ be a group and $X$ set. $a,b \in X$ are in the same orbit, so show that $stab(a) \cong stab (b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845199/let-g-be-a-group-and-x-set-a-b-in-x-are-in-the-same-orbit-so-show-that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is given that $y\in Gx$ which means that there exists $h\in G$ such that $y=hx$.

Thus, if $g\in \text{Stab}_G(y)$ then $gy=y$ hence $ghx=hx$ and so $h^{-1}ghx=x$.

In particular $g\in \text{Stab}_G(y)$ implies that $h^{-1}g h \in \text{Stab}_G(x)$.

Let $\varphi:\text{Stab}_G(y)\rightarrow \text{Stab}_G(x)$ be such that $\varphi(g)=h^{-1}gh$ we just saw above that $\varphi$ is well defined. It is also easy to check that $\varphi$ a homomorphism.

Furthermore, the inverse of $\varphi$ is given by $\varphi^{-1}(g) = hgh^{-1}$. The reason that $\varphi^{-1}$ is well defined is similar to that of $\varphi$ reversing the roles of $x,y$ .

Comment: Thank you for such a clear informative explanation!